# What are the uses of ngrams?

Tags: discussion

I do not really understand how to use *ngrams* in representative ways. How do you perceive their usefulness? Is it acceptable to base the answers essentially on *ngrams* statistics? Does it help understanding an answer about the language or does it serve to reinforce or legitimize a belief?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look to the replies to these questions asked on ELU Meta.

[How accurate is Google Ngram as a language reference source?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4284/how-accurate-is-google-ngram-as-a-language-reference-source)

[How reliable is Ngram?](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8015/how-reliable-is-ngram)

Mitch's answer summarizes them very well:

> The advice is to use ngrams with caution and always look at the actual results rather than just blindly following the graph results.
>
> NGrams is a great tool but it shouldn't be used blindly.

Answer (score 0):

Il y a beaucoup à dire sur l'utilisation des ngrams et ce qui suit ne regroupe que la plupart des aspects fondamentaux les plus évidents qui permettent de commencer à s'en servir avec profit.

Un ngram fournit la vérification qu'un usage existe, mais pas celle qu'il n'existe pas ; cela signifie que si l'on n'a aucun résultat pour une recherche l'usage n'est pas nécessairement inexistant. En utilisant les ngrams il faut toujours prendre garde à ce qu'on appelle les faux positifs, c'est à dire ces apparents résultats qui n'en sont pas et qui proviennent de données de départ mal interprétées par le programme ou par le l'utilisateur. La partie de la tâche la plus délicate du contrôle sur les faux positifs est celle qui incombe à l'utilisateur et la mener à bien repose sur sa connaissance de la grammaire et de la sémantique du langage.  Pour s'assurer de l'absence de faux positifs dus au programme, après avoir obtenu le résultat en cliquant « Search lots of books », on clique en dessous du graphe une des tranches d'années sur lesquelles la recherche est faite et on obtient ainsi les livres où possiblement l'usage a été relevé. Il faut alors vérifier les relevés, qui sont constitués d'un peu de texte avant et après le terme recherché. Le problème des faux positifs comporte plusieurs aspects fondamentaux.

A/ *Données faussées par le programme*

- a/ *ponctuation* — Par exemple dans « La fin du "tout génétique"? » le programme va relever « du tout »
  en omettant le guillemet, ce qui n'est pas la locution « du tout » dans « pas du tout fini ». Un autre exemple : on cherche « pas du tout » ; dans « […]il n'y en a pas. Du tout de cette explication il n'y a que […] » le programme va relever « pas du tout » et cette donnée ne peut donc pas compter. Quasiment toute la ponctuation cause ce problème.
- b/ *procédé informatique inapproprié pour certains livres (en particulier les livres anciens)* — les occurrences sont produites par juxtaposition d'un mot à la fin d'une lignes donné et l'autre mot au début de la ligne correspondante sur la page suivante (par ex. pour « du tout », « du » à la fin de ligne 13 page 15 et « tout » début de ligne 13 page 16).
- c/ *utilisation du même livre plusieurs fois (rééditions, maisons de publication différentes)*

B/ *Données faussées en raison de formes appartenant à plusieurs contextes linguistiques*

- e/ *continuation* — Prenons l'expression « il n'y a rien à faire » qui ne signifie pas « il n'y a aucune tâche à faire ou aucun travail ou aucune action » mais « On ne peut empêcher cela; il n'y a pas de remède à cette situation » ; dans ce cas le recherche va produire toutes les données telles que « n'y a rien à faire dans ce champs », « n'y a rien à faire avec un crayon dans ce dessin » ; de ce fait on ne peut pas compter sur la fréquence donnée parce que l'on ne peut pas savoir quelle part revient à l'expression que l'on cherche (laquelle peut d'ailleurs être 0).
- f/ *homographie* — Très évidemment, si vous voulez connaitre la fréquence du substantif « blanc » vous vous heurtez à des quantités d'occurrences de l'adjectif « blanc » qui vont être englobées dans une recherche et vont donc la fausser. Vous avez alors parfois dans ce cas des possibilités accessoires comme celle d'ajouter un article (un blanc, le blanc, des blancs) dans le présent cas, mais il faudra encore prendre en compte des constructions comme «  Les blancs flocons qui tombaient toujours l'ensevelirent » et la recherche sera toujours faussée (dans le présent cas), bien qu'à un degré moins important. Les technique possibles, lesquelles sont le produit d'une ingéniosité personnelle, ne sont pas souvent conclusives (trop de complexité, ou bien en fin de compte imparfaites).

Il existe d'autre aspects (linguistiques) de la possible fausse interprétation des résultats et parfois on pourra ne pas les déceler.

Un ngram fournit sans complication, entre autres informations, des comparaisons diverses et de nombreux contextes d'occurrence pour un terme donné.

a/ La place la plus utilisée dans un syntagme  (par ex., celle de l'adjectif) ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=un+rire+%C3%A9norme%2Cun+%C3%A9norme+rire&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cun%20rire%20%C3%A9norme%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cun%20%C3%A9norme%20rire%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cun%20rire%20%C3%A9norme%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cun%20%C3%A9norme%20rire%3B%2Cc0))

b/ La préposition préférée ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=sur+le+campus%2Cdans+le+campus&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csur%20le%20campus%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdans%20le%20campus%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Csur%20le%20campus%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdans%20le%20campus%3B%2Cc0))

c/ La plus populaire de plusieurs expressions synonymes

d/ Les fréquences relatives d'orthographes alternatives ([ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=cl%C3%A9%2Cclef&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccl%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cclef%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Ccl%C3%A9%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cclef%3B%2Cc0))

e/ Les contextes d'occurrence des termes — Pour se renseigner sur ces contextes il faut lire les relevés et éventuellement accéder aux livres et examiner les paragraphes lorsque c'est possible.

Un dernier principe utile vaut la peine d'être mentionné. Le maximum de 5 mots pour une expression à rechercher peut être porté à 6 dans certains cas, soit en n'écrivant pas le premier ou le dernier mot de l'expression, cela pour la simple raison qu'il n'y a pas d'autre forme qui puisse commencer ou finir par ce mot, selon le cas.

Un ngram peut évidemment être un atout important dans la compréhension d'un phénomène linguistique ou dans la consolidation d'une théorie.